# How to Send UserDetails Instead of Principal in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm currently working on implementing authentication in my application, and I'm using the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken class to create an authentication object. However, I'm wondering how I can send the UserDetails object instead of the principal parameter in the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken constructor.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html

public Authentication createAuthentication() {

```
public Authentication createAuthentication() {
    UserDetails userDetails = // Get the UserDetails for the authenticated user
    Object credentials = // Get the user's credentials

    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = // Get the user's authorities

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, credentials, authorities);
}
```

In the code above, I'm trying to pass the UserDetails object as the principal. Is this the correct way to send the user details, or should I be doing something differently? I want to make sure I'm following best practices for authentication in my application.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to properly send the UserDetails object in place of the principal would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't try to do that. The principal should be the unique username for this style of authentication. Spring will create a `UserDetails` implementation for you. You may then inject an `Authentication` object as a parameter to your REST controller method and use the `getDetails()` method to get the `UserDetails` in your service code (it will need to be cast to `UserDetails` because the API returns an `Object`).

Comment: In my tool for Authentication  and Authorization, I use this class UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken now. using onceperfliter I use spring security as to set the authticaiotn object in secuirtycontext. its working fine. but how to send all user details and receive in tool to set the profile. like email, first name and last name

Comment: how to set email , lastnmae and first name to user pro
public TokenTransfer authenticate(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
  Authentication authentication = authManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
  UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
  return new TokenTransfer(TokenUtils.createToken(userDetails));

Comment: please do NOT post code in comments, cant you see that is unreadable? if you wish to post code, edit your question and use the code formatting tools.

Comment: Also you are aware that giving out JWTs to browsers is a huge security risk and should never be done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem. Internally spring security also does the same as what you are doing in `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

To verify , you can see the code details starting from [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/1a45602dbb7b71ddb66bb975bd83a12ee1e1a4de/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java#L164C10-L164C27). The `principalToReturn` is actually a `UserDetails` object which will be finally used as the `principal` parameter to create a  `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`